# How to turn EF Core warnings about locally evaluated expressions to errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to turn Entity Framework Core warnings about locally evaluated expressions into errors? I'd like to force myself to always write properly evaluated queries.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression '(...)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: EF Core documentation - [Optional behavior: throw an exception for client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#optional-behavior-throw-an-exception-for-client-evaluation). Note that in the next EF Core major version [LINQ queries will no longer evaluated on the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) anyway.

Comment: @ivan-stoev, this is precisely what I was looking for, thank you. If you want, you can post a short answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'd like to force myself to always write properly evaluated queries.

Sounds like a good idea. Moreover the client evaluation idea has been considered a mistake and [will be removed in EF Core 3.0+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client), so it's good to be prepared :)

To get the desired behavior in pre 3.0, you should use the [ConfigureWarnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.configurewarnings?view=efcore-2.1) extension method to change the default action from `Log` to `Throw`, as explained in the [Optional behavior: throw an exception for client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#optional-behavior-throw-an-exception-for-client-evaluation) documentation topic:

```
optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings
    .Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning)
);
```

Additionally, it would be good to do the same for [Ignored includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes), which are another source of unexpected problems:

```
.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning)
.Throw(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning)
```

Comment: These warnings are deprecated in .NET 5.

Comment: @PeetBrits I've stumbled over this thread, as I'd like to have these errors as well, when locally evaluated. Is there a way to make this work in EF6?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller If you look at `RelationalEventId` and `CoreEventId` you will see many warnings that are currently supported, but in my code I only add these if `Debugger.IsAttached`. This way it won't break at a client.

Comment: With the latest versions of EFCore `QueryClientEvaluationWarning` is in `CoreEventId`